# How do I change line thickness in denscomp plots from the fitdistrplus package in R?

Tags: r, plot, package, density-plot

I'm over-plotting three densities onto my data histogram, using `denscomp` in the `fitdistrplus` package in `R`. The code below is working perfectly, but I don't know how to make the lines thicker.

```
denscomp(list(TryWeibull, TryGamma, TryLognormal), legendtext = plot.legend, 
     fitcol = c("indianred3","gray38", "darkblue"), fitlty = c("dashed", "longdash", "dotdash"),
     xlab = "Age", ylab  = "Proportion", main="")
```

`fitcol` is giving me the correct colours, `fitly` is giving me the correct line types, but I can't work out the command to make the lines thicker. I have two distribution densities that are close together and I have been unsuccessful in clearly identifying them using colour/line type differences. [image: The current graph].

I am trying to de-emphasize the Weibull and emphasise the gamma and lognormal. The proportions are estimates, so I am trying to fit the general shape, not the exact values.

I can't see an option in the `denscomp` function to specify line widths. I would rather not use the ggplot option, but can shift to that if required. I was hoping there was a function option I'm overlooking.

Edited to add: I raised this as a feature request on GitHub and it has been implemented into the package.

Comment: Based on the source code (https://github.com/aursiber/fitdistrplus/blob/master/R/denscomp.R) you should be able to pass `lwd=2`, or `lwd=c(1,1,2)` or similar to the `denscomp` function - have you tried that?

Comment: Thanks, I gave that a try. It's adjusting the line width in the legend, but apparently not in the plot itself. Edited to add: I'm also getting Warning message: In hist.default(mydata, plot = FALSE, ...) argument '...' is not made use of

Comment: Further testing, the width increase to the legend occurs when lwd=c(...) is used. I can use lwd=x. I still get the warning message, but all lines have increased width. It appears that the individual lines cannot be adjusted uniquely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the author of this package allows you to specify multiple line types (`fitlty`) and line colours (`fitcol`), they didn't allow you to specify multiple line widths. But since R is open-source, you are free to modify the function in any way.

Type the following at the R console:

```
fix(denscomp)
```

Then add a new argument to the function after `fitcol`, called `fitlwd`.

```
..., fitcol, fitlwd, addlegend = TRUE, ...
```

Then after line 30 add the following:

```
if (missing(fitlwd)) 
    fitlwd <- 1
```

Then after line 34 add the following:

```
fitlwd <- rep(fitlwd, length.out = nft)
```

Then modify line 136 as follows:

```
col = fitcol[i], lwd=fitlwd[i], ...)
```

Finally, modify line 142:

```
col = fitcol, lwd=fitlwd,
```

Save and call the new function as before but now specifying the `fitlwd` argument:

```
denscomp(..., fitlwd=c(1,3,3))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I will ask if the package author would consider adding this as an option into their package code.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question and followed Edward's solution, which was great and I learnt a lot, but it turned out you can just use ggplot to do that.

`denscomp(..., plotstyle = "ggplot") + geom_line(linetype = "dashed",size = 1))`